# libc.dll files is required but can not find it

Tags: dll, package, publish, ocx

I am trying to publish my application using installShield utility. Every thing works fine but it gives warning that it asks for two files:

1. libc.dll
2. Flash32_11_7_700_224.ocx

Those two files are prerequisite according to the package but I could not find them.

I tried to search in the web for those two files with no luck.

Can any one help in this?

Answer (score 2):

#### Explanation of Error

This error can be encountered in Flexera's InstallShield. The specific error is:

```
ISEXP : warning -6248: Could not find dependent file <dependent file>,
or one of its dependencies of component <component>
```

The [official troubleshooting information](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpBuildErrors.htm) from helpnet.installshield.com did not help me, but it says to:

```
Use the "Build Tables & Refresh Files" option to build the release
if the release location is in <ISProjectDataFolder> 
or <ISProjectFolder>. For more information, see "How the Run time 
Locates Assemblies", available in the .NET Framework SDK help or on MSDN.
```

#### Workaround

If the application works fine, and you just want to get rid of the warnings, you can follow this [Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008763/isexp-warning-6248-could-not-find-dependent-file-libc-dll-or-one-of-its-d).

(InstallShield, Installation Designer, Left Panel) Specify Application Data > Files

(Destination computer's files panel) Right click `primary output` > Dependencies from scan at build... > Uncheck dependencies you do not want

[image: Dependencies Dialogue]

The above picture from the Stack Overflow answerer @Tom Wilson shows what you should see. Note that `primary output` was the central .exe of my project. When I used this technique on my primary output, the other components in my project were also fixed.

#### Resolution

If this problem is crashing your application, and not just an annoying warning...

In the case of libc.dll, I would direct you to add Redistributables to your project.

(InstallShield, Installation Designer, Left Panel) Specify Application Data > Redistributables

For instance, I use Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1 Full.

I believe this solution will work for libc.dll, but cannot verify. I base this on reading [support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/94248/how-to-use-the-c-run-time), which I think implies libc.dll is contained in C Run-Time (CRT), which I would also believe is part of the .NET Framework.

In the case of [flash32_11_7_700_224.ocx](http://www.shouldiblockit.com/flash32_11_7_700_224.ocx-8db479e065f2b546bfbd7323e5ee5b02.aspx), I would direct you to System Software Requirements. This ocx is installed with many Adobe products. You may want to prompt the user that they need to install this, at the time software installation.

(InstallShield, Installation Designer, Left Panel) Define Setup Requirements and Actions > Requirements

(Central Panel) System Software Requirements > Right click > Create New Launch Condition (System Search Wizard)

[image: System search wizard]

Follow the wizard there to block installment if it does not exist, or use one of the premade requirements if that helps your case. Tip: remember to supply a link to [Adobe](https://get.adobe.com/reader/) in your prompt, so your end-user can quickly download it!