# ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file libc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component

Tags: c#, dll, installation, dependencies, installshield-le

There are many variations of this question, but my question is specific to `libc.dll`. I am not concerned on resolving the dependency. I want a work around to avoid that warning.

I have 30 projects in my Forms Application. When I publish the setup using InstallshieldLE I am getting `ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file libc.dll, or one of its dependencies of component Sample.CommonModules.ChangeUnit_.Primary_output`

warning for each primary output.

Due to this warning the publish is taking longer and killing my time. Is there a way I can bypass this warning in InstallshieldLE?

I just want get rid of that warning. I don't mind creating a mock libc.dll file and placing it some where to let the InstallShieldLE assume that it has that file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the Files view -> Right-click project Primary Output -> Select Dependencies from scan at Build -> uncheck libc.dll.

[image: Dependencies dialog showing libc.dll]

Comment: I tried this Tom, but unfortunately I dont see libc.dll listed under Dependencies.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - hope you found your answer.  Added a screenshot for other people who may see this issue in future.

Comment: This screenshot makes this answer more promising. I am gonna mark this as answer.

Answer (score 7):

For me, I went to InstallShield | Setup | Specify Application Data | Files

Within Files | Destination computer's folders | Highlighted the installation folder.

Then in the Destination computer's files right click on the primary output.  (In your instance it would be  ChangeUnit_.Primary output ) and select 'Dependencies of scan at build' and uncheck 'libc.dll'. - click on OK.

All is well (for me anyway)

Comment: I tried this Bob, but unfortunately I dont see libc.dll listed under Dependencies.